# How to set the SUID bit to grant root privileges?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

my question is super beginner! In my C program, I want to set the SUID bit (root permission) before creating a raw socket and then I want to switch back to normal permission after I have created it. Before I used to run my code using command `sudo ./client` which gave the whole executable root permissions. I want to give root permissions only to the point where I create the socket, so that I can run my code using simply `./client`.

EDIT: Realized that I have to set the SUID bit and not the sticky bit for how I want the executable to behave.

Comment: What benefit would the sticky bit give you when creating a raw socket?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler creating a raw socket requires root privileges. Thats why I'm setting the sticky bit? Also, I don't want to run the file using ```sudo ./client```. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: What relation does the sticky bit have to root privileges?  Are you thinking of the SUID (set UID) bit?  That would apply to the program.  Changing the permissions on the source code wouldn't help with that, either.  You'd have to set the permissions on the executable.  And only root can make a program SUID to root — root has to own the program and set the SUID bit.  And all that has to be done before the program is executed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So how do I make root own the executable and set the SUID bit?

Comment: With the `chown` and `chmod` programs. Please edit your title and question to reflect your actual query.

Comment: You don't need root privileges to create a raw socket; the `CAP_NET_RAW` capability suffices.  After compiling `yourbinary`, run `sudo setcap cap_net_raw=pe yourbinary` to grant that privilege to your binary executable via filesystem capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original version of the question was confusing the sticky bit (`S_ISVTX`) with the SUID or set UID bit (`S_ISUID`).  It has since been updated.

To make the program run with root privileges while creating the raw socket, you would create your executable by compiling it as normal, and then have `root` take ownership of the executable (`chown root ./client`) and set the permissions (`chmod 4555 ./client`).  Note that the permissions are carefully chosen and do not allow either group or others to write to the program (modify the executable).  The fact that the owner, `root`, has no write permission does not stop `root` from writing to the file — though `root` won't want to change it often.  Normally, `root` would copy the program to some directory where ordinary users cannot make changes.  That might conceivably be `/usr/local/bin`, or it might be somewhere else.

<sup>*Note that the permissions are set on the executable, not the source code (see the [original version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63026419/1) of the question), and must be set before the program is run.*</sup>

Inside the program, after creating the raw socket, you could remove the `root` privileges, thereby avoiding many security issues in the code after that, by executing: `setuid(getuid())`.  This changes the effective UID back to the same as the real UID.  Note that the POSIX specification for [`setuid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setuid.html)
says:

> If the process has appropriate privileges, `setuid()` shall set the real user ID, effective user ID, and the saved set-user-ID of the calling process to *uid*.

A program that is SUID to `root` has 'appropriate privileges'; there is no going back.  Using [`seteuid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/seteuid.html)
(as originally suggested) would not be as safe as using `setuid()`.